# Concatinating query strings in mysql

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I am writing a trigger in mysql and my trigger is given below:

```
$sql="CREATE TRIGGER insert_cats AFTER INSERT ON tbl_categories
   FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
   insert into tbl_routes set fld_route_name='cat_' + //here i want to concatinate
   NEW.fld_name,fld_route_info='dynamic/route/info';
   end;
";
```

i want to concat string 'cat_' with New.fld_name. I tried CONCAT but i came to know it concatinates two columns and also tried + and . operator but nothing happen...
Please help....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use concat, it works with a literal and a column too :

```
concat('cat_', New.fld_name)
```